# Unable to get fseek to work with fgetc in c

Tags: c, fseek, fgetc

I am trying to write a brainfuck interpreter in c but I can not get fseek to work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I would prefer to keep using fseek if possible. I am using fgetc to check for each brainfuck character individually and x to hold the value of fgetc. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[]){

argc--; argv++;

char array[3000];
char *program = array;
int yo = 0;
fpos_t pos;

FILE *fp;

if(*argv != NULL){
    fp = fopen(*argv,"rb");

    int x;
    int z = 1;


    while(z){

        x = fgetc(fp);

        if(x == 62){
            ++program;
        }else if(x == 60){
            --program;
        }else if(x == 43){
            ++*program;
        }else if(x == 45){
            --*program;
        }else if(x == 46){
            putchar(*program);
        }else if(x == 44){
            *program=getchar();
        }else if(x == 93){
            if(*program != 0){
                int yo = 1;
                while(yo){
                    fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                    if(fgetc(x) == 93){
                        putchar(93);
                        yo++;
                    }else if(fgetc(x) == 91){
                        putchar(91);
                        yo--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if(x == EOF){
            break;
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);
}else{
    printf("Error: no input file.\n");
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: excuse for my poor knowledge, but what do `-1L` and `0L` mean? I haven't come across this yet...

Comment: `-1L = (long)-1` `OL = (long)0`

Comment: First you seek one *byte* (or character) backward, then you seek zero bytes forward. And you never (in this piece of code) read anything from the file. Instead you have an infinite loop, where you never check if the seeks succeed.

Comment: What's the meaning of (or what did you intend to do with) `fseek(fp, zerowords, SEEK_CUR);`?

Comment: @DavidRF, can't understand why is he doing it? He tries to assign a `long` value to the variable of type `int`.

Comment: I was just trying random things to get it to work because I have little understanding of i/o programing

Comment: @JulianKhlevnoy, yes, there is no need to suffix `L` or cast in this case, `-1` and `0` are int literals

Comment: @DavidRF, does `(long)-1` == the maximum value of type `long` minus one? Or does it mean: minus one of type `long`?

Comment: @JulianKhlevnoy, no, `(long)-1` is a cast (int to long)

Comment: @JulianKhlevnoy, Julian, `-1` can be represented by `int`, the range is usually between `–2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647`

Comment: @DavidRF, I'm sorry, I've realized the stupidness of my last comment..

Comment: Give us more code! (if it is not too large) 
We can't know whether `fp` is assigned to NULL and so on...

Comment: @JulianKhlevnoy, no problem ;),  maybe you're confusing `int` with plain `char` (char can be signed or unsigned)

Comment: @DavidRF, like jokes;)  But don't confusing about it. I just had lost my concentration for a moment, so.. here is the result)

Comment: I don't see any `fgetc` here.

Comment: This is not all the code it just a snippet of it

Comment: fp = fopen(*argv,"rb"); is wrong. The first argument in argv is usually the name of the running program. You want fp = fopen(argv[1],"rb"); if(fp == NULL) {perror("Cannot open file");}

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code (it is clear so comment will be redundant):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char array[3000];
char *program = array;

FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen("hi.txt","rb");

if ( fp == NULL)
    printf("Error: no input file.\n");

int x = 0;
int size;

while(1){
    char c = fgetc(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
char j[size];
fscanf(fp, "%s", j);

if(j[x] == 62){
        ++program;
    } else if(j[x] == 60){
          --program;
    } else if(j[x] == 43){
              ++*program;
    } else if(j[x] == 45){
                  --*program;
    } else if(j[x] == 46){
                  putchar(*program);
    } else if(j[x] == 44){
          *program=getchar();
    } else if(j[x] == 93){
           if(*program != 0){
               int yo = 1;
               while(yo){
                   x--;
                   if(j[x] == 93)
                       yo++;
                   else if(j[x] == 91)
                            yo--;
                   if(yo == 0)
                       break;
               }
           }
      }  else if(j[x] == EOF){
            break;
         }
    x++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So how can I recheck the value of x?

Comment: @user2523164, so you want to read a caracter from the file and then match it to `93` or `91`?

Comment: @user2523164 as Julian says, show more code (entire loop), you have some minor problems like -1L instead of plain -1, and you fseek twice without reason

Comment: @user2523164, I've understood you! And edited my answer to try to help  you to solve your problem. (There are other functions that will read a character from the file and assign it ti the variable.)

Comment: @DavidRF, +1 ... yes) I meant that he reads but doesn't write the value that he gained.

Comment: @user2523164,  send me the text file: 
 it.is.a.postbox@gmail.com

Comment: no dose not work. also i am only using putchar for testing so i can see what x is equal to while the loop is running and at this point if it's no errored it just prints ] endlessly

Comment: so use `x = fgetc(fp)` and after it use `putchar(x)`. This will update the value of `x` and then show it to you..

Comment: I sent the files not sure if you got it.

Comment: All is ok, I received them. Can you tell me about `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`? How does it work? I haven't came across it yet...

Comment: Understood. At first I had a "no input file" in console. But now I have "segmentation fault (core dumped)". Any ideas?

Comment: what system do you run? windows?

Comment: No, Ubuntu 13.04 
but segmentation doesn't depend on OS (at least, in this case)

Comment: Just replace *argv in fopen with the file path because i have no idea whats wrong seeing as unix commands work on linux

Comment: Done, but the same "segmentation fault"

Comment: um try removing the if and else statement that checks for *argv != NULL if you have not already and change the main to just int main(){

Comment: Check your e-mail. (see the latest letter)

Comment: I'm confused. This is an answer, but it seems it's user2523164 that's teaching Julian here. Please keep the discussion down, and rather ask new questions when it's unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `fgetc(fp)` it reads a character AND ADVANCES THE CURRENT POINTER, so the next read will read the next character.  So when you do:

```
while(yo) {
    fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    if(fgetc(fp) == 93) {
        putchar(93);
        yo++; }
```

you back up a character, then read the character you just backed up over, advancing past it.  So you end up looping, reading the exact same character forever, at least until `yo` overflows and wraps back around to 0 (which may never happen as integer overflow is undefined in C).

You probably actually want `fseek(fp, -2, SEEK_CUR)` to back up to the character BEFORE the last one read.

Comment: Notice that according to the ACSII table, the output will be `(`.